# Persistent alt text flashing in Firefox when loading images

Tags: css, firefox, alt-attribute

When loading images on my site, firefox briefly (for around half a second) flashes the alt text before the image loads.

**There are other issues about this**, but everyone suggests adding

```
img:-moz-loading {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I have done so in the top-level CSS for the site, and it seemed to work in the past but has regressed. The alt text still flashes, and I can't find any alternative paths forward. There is a [closed Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1472637) without any activity in the past 5 years.

Any idea on how to dig deeper into this? From what I can tell the `img` element has nothing non-standard going on.

Comment: Is Firefox additionally flashing the broken-image-link symbol?

Comment: no, it's not, just the alt text and then the image loads

Comment: That's unhelpful, Brett. Firstly I like using this browser for many reasons, but more importantly this is for a site that users of many browsers will use.

Comment: Could you share link to your site? Or minimum reproducible example on https://stackblitz.com ? The browser version and operating system.

Comment: Hi. I'd like to point out that, in case of a slow network with a large image, temporarily seeing the alt attribute is perfectly regular, as the case of *the image hasn't finished loading yet* in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/alt).

Answer (score 3):

You can set transparent text color on the image:

```
img { color: transparent; }
```

It seems to do the job in Firefox 123. Below is the filmstrip view of the page load generated by [webpagetest.org](https://www.webpagetest.org/):

[image: webpagetest page load filmstrip view]

- The test was done on Firefox nightly on a fast 3G network. All four images have `alt`, `width`, `height` and `background-color` set.
- The top two images do not have any CSS while the bottom two images have `color: transparent`.
- The top two images display the alternate text until the image starts rendering. The bottom two images do not display the alternate text at all.

---

As for `:-moz-loading`, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-loading) says that:

> Note that images that are in the process of loading are not matched by
> this pseudo-class.

The description of "in the process of loading" is not provided but we can assume that the process starts as soon as the image is "queued" for downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, between the lines, @imhvost suggests a sort of latency at loading of images. In this case (or indeed when the link is broken), the `alt` attribute is displayed. I downloaded Firefox 123.0 (64 bits) for windows 11 and haven't noticed the issue you describe.

I made this little snippet just to ask you if it is the same behavior you're facing :

```js
function sleep(time) {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/951057/4698373
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

sleep(500).then(() => {
  const img = document.querySelector('img');
  img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200/200';
  img.dataset.imgLoaded = "true";
});
```

```html
<img src="" alt="This is my life." />
```

In that case, digging why the images are so slow to load with Firefox must be done, but we need more informations about your infrastructure and your configuration.

In the meantime, here is another snippet that could temporarily help you :

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (img of images) {
  if (img.dataset.src) {
    img.src = img.dataset.src;
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  color: transparent;
}

img[src] {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="lorem" />
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="ipsum" />
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="dolor" />
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="sit" />
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="amet" />
```

A few explanations :

- We use `img` elements dataset : `data-src` instead of src, so no image is displayed, nor `alt` attributes as their color is set to transparent by `css`.
- The script loops through the `img` collection and sets regular `src`
- By `css` rule, the `alt` color is set to black.

Certainly not the ultimate solution, but once again we need more informations, at least a location inside your infrastructure from where we could use some example images.

---

### EDIT

Please note that

> The HTMLImageElement property alt provides fallback (alternate) text
> to display when the image specified by the  element is not
> loaded.
>
> This may be the case because of an error, because the user has
> disabled the loading of images, or because the image hasn't finished
> loading yet.
> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/alt)

Comment: _and haven't noticed the issue you describe_ Actually it is easily reproducible if you use larger images, the images are not "progressive" and the image server takes a fraction of second to start sending the image. You can also use "throttling" and "disable caching" feature in Firefox dev tools > network to emulate slow network and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SalmanA, thanks for your answer. In case of a slow network with a large image, temporarily seeing the `alt` attribute is perfectly regular, as the case of *the image hasn't finished loading yet* in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/alt). So I suppose it is not browser dependent and it's the same behavior with Chrome, is it ?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you have some kind of lazy loader.
So you can hide `alt` until `img` has `src` like this:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/120/120';
  imgBroken.src = 'https://pics';
} , 1000);
```

```css
/* Hide img without src */
img:not([src]) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Нidden alt in img */
.img-hide-alt {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/120/120" class="img-hide-alt" alt="Test">

<img alt="Test" id="img">
<img alt="Test" id="imgBroken">
```

Comment: No, not doing any lazy loading. The image is created with a valid `src` right from the start.

Comment: Maybe you can share a link to the site, or make a minimal reproducible example to see the problem. Because, yes, these are just guesses now. In any case, you can still hide `alt`, as I indicated in the answer: `img { font-size: 0; }`